# list files with specific group and user name

Tags: find, users, ls, group

Do you know a command to list all files on the server with specific group and user name?

I am looking for something like this:

```
find -ls -group 'groupname' && find -ls -user 'username'
```

this has to list the file with that specific group and user name.

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439246/117549 although your particular issue isn't addressed there (order of the find primitives)

Answer (score 7):

`find` can accept multiple test primitives to determine which files (or directories, etc.) are selected for further processing by `find`.  The command:

`find / -user username`

will list all files owned by user `username`.  Likewise,

`find / -group groupname`

Will list all entries that are owned by group `groupname`.  If both tests are given on the `find` command line, the default operation is to "and" them:

`find / -user username -group groupname -ls`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` command to specify the user and group while putting multiple options in () with the `-a` switch inside.

```
find /the/path -type f \( -user username -a -group groupname \)
```

`type -f` is used to specify files. You can remove it if you also want directories and links.

The parentheses have to be escaped with backslashes.

If you want to pass it to `ls`:

```
find /the/path \( -user username -a -group groupname \) -exec ls {} \;
```

Adding `-exec -ls {} \;` at the end does that.